# Shell libraries location mechanism in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

In Linux there are standard locations for shared *binary libraries* like `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib` and a standard mechanism that allows linker to locate libraries placed there without full path specified.

I'm looking for a similar mechanism for *shell libraries* (i.e., shell scripts that are called from another shell scripts) that allows shell to locate a library even if its path isn't specified.

I know that I can find out the caller's path and calculate the path to a library from that but I don't think that's a good approach. First of all, because [there's no reliable way to determine the location of a shell script](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

So, does Linux provide a mechanism to locate shell libraries?

Comment: Nothing for most POSIX shells. `zsh` comes close with its `fpath` to indicate directories in which autoloaded functions can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shell scripts that are **called** from another shell scripts

Calling any command (that doesn't contain a `/` in the command name) is searched in `PATH`. Add your script to PATH or add a dir to PATH.

`PATH` is searched when `source`ing a script in the same way as for the command, just the command doesn't have to have executable permissions set..

Comment: Sooo obvious. How could I miss that? Thanks!